# Webpack devServer v. 4.x.x live reload not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm following these [webpack 5 guides](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/), and webpack-dev-server v4.3.1 does not live reload the sample project (a recompile does happen after editing either JavaScript file). Perhaps I have missed a step?

**1. Can you tell me where the problem lies?**

Here's my configuration:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.7",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "postcss": "^8.3.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.16",
    "webpack": "^5.58.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "components"
  },
  "author": "Karl",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    print: './src/print.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: { 
            directory: './dist',
            watch: true
        },
  },
    plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management',
    }),
  ],
    output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    }
};
```

Below is the result of running the npm start script (the 2 files in ./src, index.js and the print.js, are copied from the above linked guide). If I edit either file, live reload does not work, but after manually refreshing the browser the edits are reflected.

[image]

If it matters, the above is from VS Code's Bash terminal, and I'm running Windows 10.

**2) BONUS: What configuration changes do I need to make in order to live reload a static index.html file located in the project's root folder?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This configuration should do the trick:

```js
devServer: {
    hot: false, // optional, but you must not set both hot and liveReload to true
    liveReload: true
}
```

The live-reloading of the static index.html can be achieved with this plugin configuration:

```js
plugins: [
  ...,
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "src/index.html" })
]
```

Comment: I was ready to answer my own question, but I see you beat me to it. Seems strange that the default values for both options, i.e. true are incompatible. Note though, they can both be true if `devServer.watchFiles` is configured, [per the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwatchfiles). Also, the guides do not mention that `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` needs to be installed and it was not auto added to my node modules as the webpack docs imply it should be. I'm still not able to auto reload a static index.html file. Perhaps I'll post another question.

Comment: My static index.html is live-reloaded with this plugin configuration: `new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: "src/index.html" })`. I find it fascinating, how webpack leads to very different outcomes with very similar configurations.

Comment: There is even more to it. Webpack allows to automatically reload only the blocks of code that were changed, and without generation of both /dist folder and index.html, as in your case. It is called Hot Module Reload. [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445288/enabling-webpack-hot-reload-in-a-docker-application/72717329#72717329)